# How to write numbers as 4-bit elements to a file?

Tags: java, file, int

I want to save space when writing my data to file. That is I want to store my int numbers as half byte (4bits) only for each digit. I can't write numbers as characters as that will cost one byte for each digit (the corresponding ASCII code)

I am using the following code to get rid of the first half of the byte and write only 4 bits:

```
String key= "1234567890"
char[] chars = key.toCharArray();
System.out.println(key+";");
dos.writeLong(l);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < chars.length ; i+= 2 ) {
    byte b1 = (byte) (chars[i] - (byte) '0');
    byte b2 = (byte) (i < chars.length-1 ? chars[i+1] - (byte) '0': 0xf);
    fos.write((byte) ((b1 << 4) | b2 ));
```

and this code to read back:

```
String encoded = stt.nextToken( );
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
byte[] buf = encoded.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++ ) {
    byte both = (byte) bais.read();
    byte b1 = (byte) ((both >> 4 ) & 0xf);
    byte b2 = (byte) (both  & 0xf) ;
    result.append( Character.forDigit(b1, 10));
    if ( b2 != 0xf ) {
        result.append(Character.forDigit(b2,10));
    }
}
```

It's not working. How could I improve this?

Comment: you must implement an integer encoder.

Comment: what does "not work" mean. Please elaborate and be more specific. Any error message? If so what are they?

Comment: If you want to compress your output I suggest using an already available solution like gzip or maybe huffman encoding. Solutions like yours are going to be a lot of work and compress probably worse than gzip.

Comment: @vidstige  it works for part of the string and it does not encode the string as a whole. Also it does not work for all strings try "98476" for example

Comment: @GeorgSchölly that will require too much processing time. what do u think?1

Comment: CPU time is cheap. The compressing will be much faster than your disk is able to write. However, you loose random access and I think if your file gets corrupted you can't extract it partially.

Comment: Why are you using a `ByteArrayInputStream` if you already have an array of bytes?  Why not just access it directly?  That would get rid of a lot of overhead if you're really concerned with CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done a bit of data stream compression myself, I would suggest another approach: open a ZIP output stream, and write your full data in it. The compression algorithm will take charge of eliminating useless bits (including those you didn't identify). As a bonus, your code will be easier to read.

Comment: this is not an answer to his question, and your suggestion is not applicable anyway in any context where his naïve integer encoding could be useful. What if he's trying to implement an LZ77 compressor, for example?

Comment: I do not think it would be efficient as it will consume long processing time.. 
I care a lot about timing in my application!

Comment: For a single file, I would use GZIP.

Comment: @shaklasah, Since you care about performance you will have tried GZIP or similar compression and can tell us exactly how much slower it is, rather than guess it will be slower. ;)  If you disk or network is slow enough, it will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need a good implementation of a [prefix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), which represents each symbol individually without caring of the context.

There are a bunch of codes, each with a space/time trade-off and each one more suitable versus a given symbol probability distribution.

For example, [gamma code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) yields good compression ratios for symbols monotonically distributed, but it is costly due to explicit shifts required to get back the numbers, while [byte-variable encoding](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/variable-byte-codes-1.html) is relatively cheap but yields modest compression ratios.

In general, [Huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is a method that gives you the optimal code (i.e., the one that yields the best compression ratio) and highly tuned implementations exists, due to its prominence (e.g., methods based on the canonical representation are very fast), but it needs the probability distribution of your symbols, so it depends on the context and thus requires more care to implement it.

In a nutshell: give them a try and pick the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Seems a very complicated way of doing something very simple.

Comment: @DJClayworth: why? That's basic stuff in data compression, and there are libraries that implements those methods (which are very easy to implement, nevertheless) and have very intuitive interfaces. There might be easier way to do it, from a programming point of view (compressed streams), but it really depends on what his application is trying to do, that's up to him.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, are you absolutely sure you need to do this? Disk space is cheap. You need to be working literally with billions of values before this is worthwhile. Even if you are downloading this data, megabytes are essentially trivial.
2. If you do need to do this the easiest way is to write the numbers in an easy format - even ASCII encoding - and then use compression to get the size down. These methods are almost certainly going to give you a smaller file than anything you code yourself - sometimes provably so. Write to a .zip output stream, or just write the regular file and run a compression utility, whichever is easier.
3. If for some reason neither options 1 or 2 work for you, then your approach is the right one. Write two values to a byte using bit shift and then write the byte array.

As for exactly why your code doesn't work you will need to give us more information about what exactly is going wrong.